# Can I use a Dual Boot and VM with the same installation?

Tags: windows, dual-boot, virtualization

I have been running Ubuntu inside a VM for the past 6 months or so, but I am struggling to get great performance out of it. My goal is to be able to setup a dual boot of Windows and Ubuntu, so that when I really need performance I can just boot into Ubuntu, but for other times when I need to use Windows, I can still pop open the boot instance of Ubuntu in a VM.

Is this possible? I have done this in Parallels for Mac, but I'm not aware of anything that will allow me to do this in Windows.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to use the same instance of Ubuntu in both the VM and dual boot methods, correct? This may be possible, I guess it depends on which VM software you're using. If it supports booting from a partition and not just a virtual drive, then you'd be good to go. You should include the software you're using, and someone that knows about it might be able to answer your question.

Comment: @root45 - Yes, I want to boot the same instance. I don't care which software I use to accomplish the task, but currently I am using VirtualBox. I don't mind switching though, if there is something that supports this.

Comment: Heres the sources i used to make a both ways setup, dual boot Win 10 and Lin, both bootable from each other using Vbox to boot the other. Successful, but some issues with power management in Win (a HP elitebook laptop) and succesful only with legacy, not UEFI https://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2016/02/running-a-real-windows-install-in-virtualbox-on-linux/ https://lifehacker.com/how-to-dual-boot-and-virtualize-the-same-partition-on-y-493223329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that [Kris Harper's post](https://askubuntu.com/a/57543/618353) has the exact answer to the question.

> The `menu.lst` file was part of the original GRUB. Ubuntu now uses GRUB2 by default, so the config file has changed to `/boot/grub.cfg`.
>
> [Here is](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275) a rather long primer about GRUB2. Scroll down to section 5 to read about editing the GRUB config file. Note that you shouldn't edit this file directly in normal circumstances. Instead, editing `/etc/default/grub` is the preferred way to prevent overwriting your changes on update.
>
> [Here's](http://linuxers.org/howto/how-configure-grub2-ubuntu-910) another primer on editing the GRUB2 config file. It's not as technical.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why this should be impossible. Let's break down the steps:

1. VirtualBox on Windows probably uses a file on the Windows filesystem to store the guest (Ubuntu) virtual HDD. Learn how to use a partition instead.
2. Once, you have a real Ubuntu partition, set up a bootloader (grub) or modify the bootloader you already have.
3. Now, boot into Ubuntu. Ubuntu should recognize your hardware (which is different from the emulated hardware when running inside VirtualBox). If your hardware is supported, see if VirtualBox guest additions (graphics, networking) cause any trouble. Check whether networking needs work.
4. Go back to Windows and see if Ubuntu under VirtualBox still works.
5. Be very careful with hibernating Ubuntu.