# How to create Grub boot disk?

Tags: 11.04, grub2, virtualbox, dual-boot

So I'm doing a test. I've installed Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.04 side-by-side. Now, I'd like to be able to launch the Ubuntu install from within Windows using VirtualBox. I was following the instructions [here](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/784138-howto-boot-existing-ubuntu-partition-using-virtualbox-inside-windows/) but they don't seem to apply to 11.04.

I got stuck on step 2. `/usr/lib/grub/*-pc/stage2_eltorito` and `/boot/grub/menu.lst` don't exist. If you can tell me where to find those, that would be a good start. However, using `find / -name menu.lst` yielded no results.

How do I create a Grub boot disk that I can use with VirtualBox in 11.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `menu.lst` file was part of the original GRUB. Ubuntu now uses GRUB2 by default, so the config file has changed to `/boot/grub.cfg`.

[Here is](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275) a rather long primer about GRUB2. Scroll down to section 5 to read about editing the GRUB config file. Note that you shouldn't edit this file directly in normal circumstances. Instead, editing `/etc/default/grub` is the preferred way to prevent overwriting your changes on update.

[Here's](http://linuxers.org/howto/how-configure-grub2-ubuntu-910) another primer on editing the GRUB2 config file. It's not as technical.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Would you happen to know where the `stage2_eltorito` moved to?

Comment: I would use [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Making-a-GRUB-bootable-CD_002dROM) (section 3.2). It seems to mirror your original tutorial pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. @root45, thanks for the link. Turns out the boot disk wasn't even required. I just hooked the VM up to the VMDK which pointed to the physical drive.

Comment: Awesome. Glad it's working.